# AWS ec2 en_US.UTF-8 issue

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.03-release-notes/

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)
[ec2-user@ip-10-136-14-68 ~]$ vi ~/.bash_profile
[ec2-user@ip-10-136-14-68 ~]$ 


    # .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

how do you solve this?

Comment: Hi, Can you give more details about the issue?

Comment: Generally this kind of locale problem is caused by the SSH server. I think [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144235/locale-variables-have-no-effect-in-remote-shell-perl-warning-setting-locale-f) explains it very well.

Answer (score 50):

Another solution is to add these lines to `/etc/environment`

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

The next time you log in the warning message should have disappeared.

Comment: In fact, the message disappeared! But I have no idea what I just did.

Comment: This sets the translations ([locales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)) for the BASH command line environment to US English. Alternative locales are available for most languages from package management.

Comment: Why is this not set by default on Amazon Linux 5 years later? That is the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Open your `ssh_config` file (in my case under **Ubuntu** it's located here : `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), and comment this line:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

This means :

```
#SendEnv LANG LC_*
```